How to utilize Rauh's German Political Sentiment Dictionary
I need to utlize the named sentiment dictionary for my sentiment analysis in R studio. Unfortunately I have problems at that. The dictionary comes within a zip archive and specifically (as I assume) in 2 .Rdata files ( "Rauh_SentDictionaryGerman_Negation"; "Rauh_SentDictionaryGerman").
I tried to follow this (underneath) guideline, but did not work so far.
https://rdrr.io/github/quanteda/quanteda.sentiment/src/sources/Rauh/create-data_dictionary_Rauh.R
#' Rauh's German Political Sentiment Dictionary

library("quanteda")
library("dplyr")

# load dictionary dataframes (downloaded here: https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/BKBX)
load("Rauh/Rauh_SentDictionaryGerman_Negation.Rdata")
load("Rauh/Rauh_SentDictionaryGerman.Rdata")

# new column where NOT and word are divided with a space
neg.sent.dictionary <- neg.sent.dictionary %>% 
    mutate(word = gsub("NOT_", "NOT ", feature)) %>% 
    mutate(sentiment = ifelse(sentiment == 1, "neg_negative", "neg_positive"))

sent.dictionary <- sent.dictionary %>% 
    mutate(word = feature) %>% 
    mutate(sentiment = ifelse(sentiment == -1, "negative", "positive"))

# bind both dataframes
sent_dictionary_rauh <- bind_rows(sent.dictionary, neg.sent.dictionary)

# save as quanteda dictionary (word and sentiment column)
data_dictionary_Rauh <- quanteda::as.dictionary(sent_dictionary_rauh)

data_dictionary_Rauh <- as.dictionary(data_dictionary_Rauh)
meta(data_dictionary_Rauh) <- 
  list(
    title = "Rauh's German Political Sentiment Dictionary",
    description = "A quanteda dictionary object containing the dictionaries provided in Rauh (forthcoming). Rauh assesses its performance against human intuition of sentiment in German political language (parliamentary speeches, party manifestos, and media coverage). The resource builds on, harmonizes and extends the SentiWS (Remus et al. 2010) and GermanPolarityClues (Waltinger 2010) dictionaries. In order to use the negation correction provided by the dictionary, currently a combination of tokens_replace and tokens_compound is required to harmonize the five covered bi-gram patterns prior to scoring. The example below shows how to conduct this transformation. Note that the process changes the terms 'nicht|nichts|kein|keine|keinen' to a joint term altering some of the features of the original corpus.",
    url = "https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/BKBXWD",
    reference = "Rauh, C. (2018). Validating a Sentiment Dictionary for German Political Language: A Workbench Note. Journal of Information Technology & Politics, 15(4), 319-343.

Remus, R., Quasthoff U., & Heyer, G. (2010). \"SentiWS - a Publicly Available German-language Resource for Sentiment Analysis.\" In Proceedings of the 7th International Language Resources and Evaluation (LREC'10), 1168-1171.

Waltinger, U. (2010). \"GermanPolarityClues: A Lexical Resource for German Sentiment Analysis.\" In International Conference on Language Resources and Evaluation, 17-23 May 2010 LREC'10.",
    license = "Unknown"
    )


polarity(data_dictionary_Rauh) <- 
  list(pos = c("positive", "neg_negative"), neg = c("negative", "neg_positive"))

usethis::use_data(data_dictionary_Rauh, overwrite = TRUE)

Do I have to manually construct the "polarity()" function at first?
Despite this, I cannot rly get a grasp of how these two files are structured.
Whith "readLines()" I think not all information gets conveyed (f.i. wether the terms belong to  key positive, negative, neg_negative or neg_positive) Same holds for other ways of trying to convert them into text files before moving on. Perhaps they are .Rdata files for a reason haha
After loading them in with load() and pursuing print() to get a sense of the structure I receive [1] "neg.sent.dictionary" [1] "sent.dictionary". So I guess all terms are in row 1. But is the additional info (sentiment category/key) even contained in those two files or do I have to manually bind these with the files of the "SentiWS" and "GermanPolarityClues", which are also in the archive? How can I access the keys?
In the end I simply want to convert the dictionary in a tibble (tidy verse, tidy text) with columns "Line", "word", "category/key" (positive etc.)
Does sb know a helpful guide to utilize the dictionary? Or knows ho to do so?
Antwort auf deutsch wird nat auch begrüßt.
Thanks a lot in forward!

Try the quanteda.sentiment package, it has the Rauh dictionary built in:
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 4.0.2
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 71.1
#> Parallel computing: disabled
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
# remotes::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.sentiment")
library("quanteda.sentiment")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'quanteda.sentiment'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:quanteda':
#> 
#>     data_dictionary_LSD2015

txt <- c(
    "Mit keinem guten Ergebniss",
    "Das ist gar nicht mal so gut",
    "Total awesome!",
    "nicht so schlecht wie erwartet",
    "Der Test verlief positiv.",
    "Sie fährt ein grünes Auto."
)

textstat_polarity(txt, dictionary = data_dictionary_Rauh)
#>   doc_id sentiment
#> 1  text1  1.098612
#> 2  text2  0.000000
#> 3  text3  0.000000
#> 4  text4 -1.609438
#> 5  text5  1.098612
#> 6  text6  0.000000

Created on 2024-06-26 with reprex v2.1.0
